# compare string with type of variables

Tags: c

Hello im in need of some help this part of my program is to get a input string like 2x³+2y² and separate it in 2 arrays termos=terms and exp=exponential, however i cant seem to get it working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  char poly[50];
  int termos[10];
  int exp[10];
  int contt=0, conte=0, i=0;
  char var1, var2, var3;

  printf("Introduza o polinómio\n");
  scanf("%s", &poly);

  for(i=0; i<50; i++)
  {
    if(poly[i-1]==char && poly[i]==int && poly[i-1]!='+')
    {
      exp[conte]=poly[i];
      conte++;
    }

    if(poly[i]==int)
    {
      termos[contt]=poly[i];
      contt++;
    }

    if(poly[i]=='x')
      var1=poly[i];
    if(poly[i]=='y')
      var2=poly[i];
    if(poly[i]=='z')
      var3=poly[i];
  }
```

Comment: Please review your indices in your for loop. Starting with i = 0 and trying to retrieve [i - 1] isn't right.

Comment: Code likely should not loop to the end of the array, but the end of the string: `for(i=0; i<50; i++)` --> `for(i=0; poly[i]; i++)`

Comment: `for(i=0; i<50; i++)` isn't correct because the input string can be shorter. Use: `i=0; while (poly[i]!='\0') { ... i++;}`

Comment: Typically only the coefficients are stored. There is no need to store the exponents, just use `0` coefficients for the unused terms.

Answer (score 0):

Simply impossible, there is not runtime type information in [c](/questions/tagged/c). Perhaps you should read [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and ask another question later.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
if(poly[i-1]==char && poly[i]==int && poly[i-1]!='+')
```

you want to know if `poly[i-1]` is an alphabetic character, e.g. an 'a', or is a number. You can use the following functions from ctype.h for that:

```
// among the includes
#include <ctype.h>

// later
if(isalpha(poly[i-1]) && isdigit(poly[i]) && poly[i-1]!='+')
```

There are more problems in your code. We will post these as comments.

Comment: like  changing the save to `exp[]` to ` exp[conte]=poly[i] - '0'; // translate from ASCII digit to number`

Comment: btw, using `exp[]` may be a confusing name because `exp(n)` is a common antilog function